# Execution time in for loop is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, elapsedtime

I have a code like this:

```
string str = "";
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
    ...........
    str += ...;
}
return str;
```

but, this code is very slow, and when execute, it takes 7 minutes.

Do you think a solution would be?

Comment: seems like space allocation.
Could you try the same with a stringbuilder and see if you get an increase in performance? Could also be the actions you didn't mention (in the .........)

Comment: Because each time you add string to string it makes a new string and shuffles all the memory about.

Comment: It's an O(N^2) operation, so no wonder it's slow.

Comment: Maybe your `...........` is the problem. But in general use a `StringBuilder`

Comment: What else is there in your code in the place of `.....`?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for that link. Time to add that to my lovely collection already containing gems like _Bobby Tables_ and _Parse HTML With Regex_.

Comment: I found a solution :)

inside the loop, use List<string> instead of string.

    List<string> lst= new List<string>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
        ...........
        lst.Add(...);
    }
    return String.Join("", lst.ToArray());;

it is very very fast.

Comment: @asadynet Really, just use `StringBuilder`. It's what it's for. `String.Join` is specifically for adding separators between the strings.

Answer (score 3):

The benefits of **StringBuilder** should be perfect useful with huge strings.

In your example, every time you concatenate a string (`str += ....`) you create a **new** string object, and it becomes longer, the more time execution is needed to copy from the **old** string to the **new** string.

Here is a demonstration how it works at `memory` level.

[image]

`StringBuilder` actions different. It was included exactly for this type of problem. So, `.NET Framework` includes `StringBuilder` class which is optimized for **string** `concatenation`.

So `StringBuilder` should perform better in your situation.

Comment: Despite having not free hand draw and nothing paint in red but here is my +1.